# Flutter: How to like and unlike a post using like button package

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a project where I want to like and unlike an image. I wanted it a little fancy, so I used the package [like_button]https://pub.dev/packages/like_button). I watched an online tutorial for this, and for them, it worked for me it didn't work. Also, I want to update the number of like in the firebase.
In the documentation, it asks us to use onTap() which I did but unfortunately, it's not working. Kindly help me with the solution.
NOTE: I am not getting any error it's just that I like an image but after hot reload it doesn't update.

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:like_button/like_button.dart';

class LikeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  int likeCount = 0;
  bool isLiked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  LikeButton(
      isLiked: isLiked,
      likeCount: likeCount,
      circleColor:
    CircleColor(start: Colors.deepPurple, end: Colors.deepPurple.shade300),
      bubblesColor: BubblesColor(
        dotPrimaryColor: Colors.deepPurple.shade500,
        dotSecondaryColor: Colors.deepPurple.shade200,
      ),
      // likeCount: likeCount,
      countPostion: CountPostion.bottom,
      likeCountPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 18),
      countBuilder: (count, isLiked, text){
        final color = Colors.deepPurpleAccent[200];
        return Text(
          '$text likes',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: color,
            fontFamily: 'Sen',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        );
      },
      likeBuilder: (isLiked) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            size: 26,
            color: isLiked ? Colors.deepPurpleAccent : Colors.grey,
          ),
        );
      },
      onTap: (isLiked) async {
        this.isLiked = isLiked;
        likeCount += this.isLiked ? 1 : -1;
        return !isLiked;
      },
    );
  }
}

```
`

Here the code is being called...

    Row(
                    children: [
                      LikeAnimation(),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6),
                        child: Image.asset('Icons/comment.png', color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100],width: 20,),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
````

Comment: What part is not working? Is there an error response? could show an image or a copy of the error response

Comment: Meanwhile try to look at their example: https://github.com/fluttercandies/like_button/blob/master/example/lib/pages/like_button_demo.dart

Comment: No, I am not getting any errors it's just that after hitting the like button it increments but once I hot reload it goes back to 0. No update in number, it should be 1 but it's not updating and remains 0

Comment: Could you include the  code of where the LikeButton is attached?

Comment: Sure I did, attached the code

Answer (score 1):

use this in OnTap

```
    // Use setState to update the state of the widget

        setState(() {
      this.isLiked = isLiked;
      likeCount += this.isLiked ? 1 : -1;
    });
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. It should be in a way how Instagram like works but using setState just make it badly formatted that too give negative numbers

Comment: of course you will get 0 every hot reload because you're set the   int likeCount = 0;
 every time your state is rebuild so make sure to get the data from firebase and update call them every time you update your wedgit and make sure to not decreese the number of like count if is 0 to not get under 0 by make if statment

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think the like button stores the number of likes. If you close the page and open it, you will still have the same effect as hot reload.

However this is my suggestion on how to do this:

```dart
class LikeAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  const LikeAnimation({ super.key });

  @override
  State<LikeAnimation> createState() => _LikeAnimationState();
}

class _LikeAnimationState extends State<LikeAnimation> {
  int likeCount = 0;
  bool isLiked = false;
  var likeDB = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Likes");
  String uid = "";
  String imageId = ''; //the image should have an id

  @override
  void initState(){
  super.initState();
  uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
  //Assuming I have a collection I would do like this
  likeDB.doc("$uid_$imageId").get().then((snapshot){
 //If such document exist I know the user has liked the image or media file
 if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null){
    setState((){
      isLiked = true;
    });
 }
});
//I define a document called total likes in cloud firestore
likeDB.doc("total_likes").get().then((snapshot){
 //If such document exist I know the user has liked the image or media file
 if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null){
   setState((){
     likeCount = snapshot.data['count'];
   });
 }
});
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  LikeButton(
      isLiked: isLiked,
      likeCount: likeCount,
      circleColor:
    CircleColor(start: Colors.deepPurple, end: Colors.deepPurple.shade300),
      bubblesColor: BubblesColor(
        dotPrimaryColor: Colors.deepPurple.shade500,
        dotSecondaryColor: Colors.deepPurple.shade200,
      ),
      // likeCount: likeCount,
      countPostion: CountPostion.bottom,
      likeCountPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 18),
      countBuilder: (count, isLiked, text){
        final color = Colors.deepPurpleAccent[200];
        return Text(
          '$text likes',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: color,
            fontFamily: 'Sen',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        );
      },
      likeBuilder: (isLiked) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            size: 26,
            color: isLiked ? Colors.deepPurpleAccent : Colors.grey,
          ),
        );
      },
      onTap: (isLiked) async {
        this.isLiked = isLiked;
        likeCount += this.isLiked ? 1 : -1;
        //This may take time to update the UI
        if(isLiked == true){
         await likeDB.doc('$uid_$imageId').set({'value': true});
         } else {
          await likeDB.doc('$uid_$imageId').delete();
         }
        return !isLiked;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then for `total_likes` you should use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/overview/). **OnCreate** method should be used to increment `(+1)` count in the database and **OnDelete** should be used decrement `(-1)` count in the database.

Comment: take a look at this answer

Answer (score -1):

You have to store userID whoever user liked the image and then you have check wether the logged-in user liked it or not. So, based upon userID(s) you can make like button to true or false.